# On ground wave propagation

Tags: short-circuits

My textbook says, (ground wave propagation)
"Horizontal component of electric field in contact with the earth is short circuited"
I am not understanding, what do you mean by short circuited electric field. Please explain.

Comment: It means that the electric field is perpendicular to the surface because the tangential component is zero, i.e., short-circuited.

Answer (score 1):

it means the zones of maximum induced voltage in the ground are connected together by a good conductor (the ground) which acts as a current shunt- that is, a short-circuit.